# Authentication using selenium chrome webdriver and task scheduler

Tags: python, selenium, win32com

I found and used the following code to do authentication with Python3.6 and Chrome Webdriver.

```
driver.get(url)
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")   
shell.Sendkeys(username)  
shell.Sendkeys("{TAB}")
shell.Sendkeys(password) 
shell.Sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```

It worked perfectly fine until I had to schedule the script in Windows task scheduler. When the authentication box fires, instead of entering username and password in the field, they are output in `cmd` or press windows 'Start' icon and pause there. My intuition is I have to fix the object name to Chrome webtab in `win32com.client.Dispatch`, but after several hours of research, I still have no clue.

I also tried other ways to do authentication but this one is by far the only one works. Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to capture the auth box before sendkeys?

Comment: That is what I think too. But no idea how to do so.